# An index based on a scalar function applied to a column

Tags: sql-server, indexing, user-defined-functions

I have an user scalar-valued function which takes NVARCHAR(MAX) and returns NVARCHAR(MAX). To increase perfomance of GROUP BY command utilizing this function I wanted to create an index also based on it. But [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) says what CREATE INDEX command only takes columns not expressions, so this is illegal:

```
CREATE INDEX an_index ON a_table (foo(a_column))
```

Are any workarounds?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE a_table (a_column NVARCHAR(MAX), a_foo AS foo(a_column))
CREATE INDEX an_index ON a_table (a_foo)
```

In order to be indexable, the function `foo` must, of course, meet certain demands:

> Indexing Computed Columns That Invoke a User-Defined Function
>
> A computed column that invokes a user-defined function can be used in an index when the user-defined function has the following property values:
>
> - `IsDeterministic = true`
> - `IsSystemVerified = true` (unless the computed column is persisted)
> - `UserDataAccess = false`
> - `SystemDataAccess = false`

You cannot build an index on a non-deterministic function like `GETDATE` that changes its return value every time you call it.

It will be even easier to solve your case if you post the function you want to index on.